# need to set a custom id to a hook in WHMCS cant get this to work

Tags: php, whmcs

hi i need to set the navbar of my HOME in whmcs a class or id of('testhook')

```
    <?php

use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar)
{
   if (!is_null($primaryNavbar->getChild('Home'))) {
           $primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')
                        ->setID('testhook');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing html id attribute seems not possible, how about adding a custom class with the following code:

```
$primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')->setClass('testhook');
```

Comment: hi thank you i have tried this before and it does not change

Comment: @viit I gave you working code example, I tested it on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://classdocs.whmcs.com/7.6/WHMCS/View/Menu/Item.html
I believe you only can set class name for menu item
https://classdocs.whmcs.com/7.6/WHMCS/View/Menu/Item.html#method_setClass
Something like:

```
<?php

use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;

add_hook('ClientAreaPrimaryNavbar', 1, function (MenuItem $primaryNavbar)
{
    if(!$primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')) {
        return;
    }
    $primaryNavbar->getChild('Home')->setClass('<classname_without_dot>');
});
```

Can also use `MenuItem::setBodyHTML(string $html)` to add something extra